# Choosing a FontProviderImp in iTextSharp

Tags: itext, html-to-pdf, pdf-parsing

I am using XMLWorker for parsing html. I have been having some issues with the fonts I define in the styles. For example, something simple as this:

```
<span style="font-family: Garamond">Foo Garamond</span>
```

wasn't not working.

I was using this as my css applier:

```
CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl();
```

In order to check if it was a problem with the encoding of the html, or any other issue..., I did my own implementation of the IFontProvider:

```
class MyFontProvider : IFontProvider
    {
        public bool IsRegistered(string fontname)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public Font GetFont(string fontname, string encoding, bool embedded, float size, int style, BaseColor color)
        {
            var font = FontFactory.GetFont(fontname, encoding, embedded, size, style, color);
            return new Font(font);
        }
    }
```

Then, this:

```
CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl(new MyFontProvider());
```

Great!!!, that works fine!!!, also if I passed to the constructor this:

```
CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl(new XMLWorkerFontProvider());
```

also works.

So, it is obvious that the default implementation of the font provider is not working. I  defined it as this:

```
CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl();

or 

CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl(new FontFactoryImp());
```

, and neither worked.

My questions are:

1. What possible explanation has this?
2. Differences between `XMLWorkerFontProvider` and `FontFactoryImp` implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FontFactoryImp`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/FontFactoryImp.cs) is part of iText/iTextSharp core. It provides access to the required core 14 fonts and allows you to optionally register additional font files and give them nice names. But unless you manually register a font file it will just return the "default" font.

[`XMLWorkerFontProvider`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/XMLWorkerFontProvider.cs) is part of `XMLWorker` and is actually a subclass of `FontFactoryImp`. The biggest difference between the two is that if you use the empty constructor on `XMLWorkerFontProvider` it actually calls `base.RegisterDirectories()` which registeres **every** font in the system font folder. Depending on the number of fonts you have this could be expensive which is why the default version doesn't do it.